# The semaphore timeout period has expired while restoring .bak file in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error message `The semaphore timeout period has expired` when I am trying to restoring a `.bak` file. This is a huge file(36GB) Can you please suggest me how to restore the `.bak` file.

I need to restore the backup file to SQL server 2008 database.

Comment: Please post the full error message (I suspect there are multiple).

Answer (score 1):

36GB is not a huge file to restore

It sounds more like a network issue where the communication is broken rather than a SQL based issue.

Are you running the restore command remotely or on the host machine?
Is the backup file on a remote network location or on the host machine?

I would say that if you are running the command remotely or the backup file is on a different network path that you try to bring either the file or the SSMS connection locally to the SQL instance.

Comment: I had the same issue and the backup file was on the same machine as the SQL Server installation, could it be to do with an activity timeout of the Management Studio itself?